How can I format the name of a nomenclature subgoup to look like the one of a \subsubsection?
I have a very similar problem to the one solved here.
Instead of the whole nomenclature, I'd like to change the formatting of the nomenclature groups.
Currently I have:
\renewcommand{\nomgroup}[1]{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{A}}{\item[\textbf{Abbreviations}]}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{G}}{\item[\textbf{Greek Symbols}]}{}}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{L}}{\item[\textbf{Latin Symbols}]}{}}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{S}}{\item[\textbf{Subscripts, Superscripts, and Accents}]}{}}{%
\ifthenelse{\equal{#1}{O}}{\item[\textbf{Operators and Mathematical Notation}]}{}}}

but the output from \textbf{} is not the same as the one from \subsubsection{}:

[\subsubsection above, \textbf below]
Is there a way to change that \renewcommand to achieve what I need?
